# C procedure entry point inet_ntop WS2_32.dll on XP?

Tags: c, windows, windows-xp

I am getting an error on windows xp "The procedure entry point inet_ntop could not be located in the dynamic link library WS2_32.dll" and after some Googling I found that inet_ntop is not available in XP, so I made a Macro to use inet_ntoa instead. But it doesn't seem to be working, I still get the same error... Am I missing something?

```
char *get_ip(char *host)
{
    struct hostent *hent;
    int iplen = 39;
    long errorcode;
    char *ip = (char *)malloc(iplen + 1);
    memset(ip, 0, iplen + 1);

    if ((hent = gethostbyname(host)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not get the IP address");
        exit(1);
    }

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x600)
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *)hent->h_addr_list[0], ip, iplen) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not resolve the host");
        exit(1);
    }
#else
    ip = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hent->h_addr_list[0]));
    if (ip == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not resolve the host");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    return ip;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to switch behaviour at runtime. Instead it uses conditional compilation which determines behaviour at compile time. Your #if code is evaluated at compile time. Not what you intended I expect. Only one of those branches is actually compiled. Again, not what you expected I am sure.

You need to use run time linking (LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress) and check the version of the OS at runtime to determine behaviour.